# Create Jquery datepicker in dynamically generated table rows

Tags: jquery, datepicker

```
function AddDatepicker() {                 
    $('#Ecd').datetimepicker();    
}

$(document).on("click", "#btnAdd", function () {             

    var $new_row = $("<tr>" +
        "<td><input type='text' id='Ecd' /></td>" +
        "</tr>");

    var $EcdTextbox = $new_row.find('text');

    $EcdTextbox.append(AddDatePicker()); 

   $("#tblWorkpack tbody").append($new_row);


});
```

For Some reason I need to create dynamic table in the above written way only as there are other rows as well.  I need to add datepicker in dynamically generated table rows. The above function only works for the first row and fails for the following rows. Please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done simply like this.

Just add the datepicker on the new input elements. And you can't append a function to an element. And if you are trying to find and input field type text you need to write .find('input[type="text"]') not find('text') :)
And never generate dynamic elements with same id names :)

```js
$(document).on("click", "#btnAdd", function() {

  var $new_row = $("<tr><td><input type='text' class='Ecd' /></td></tr>");

  $new_row.find('input').datepicker();


  $("#tblWorkpack tbody").append($new_row);


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<table id="tblWorkpack">
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>

<div id="btnAdd">Add Row</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Bojan, It did work for me and it started showing me the Calender. But now I ran into another problem of how to validate whether the date has been selected or not while posting back the form. Also, I am not able to read the value of the textbox that contains the date.